# Delete part of string based on a pattern

Tags: r

I would like to know how could I find a pattern to delete certain part of every string in a vector.

```
stri<-c("protein mono-ADP-ribosylation (GO:0140289)","negative regulation of viral life cycle (GO:1903901)","viral life cycle (GO:1901)")
```

More specifically everything inside the parenthesis and the parentheses of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
gsub('\\s\\(.*', '', stri)
```

Output:

```
[1] "protein mono-ADP-ribosylation"           "negative regulation of viral life cycle" "viral life cycle"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("\\s*\\(.*\\)\\s*", "", stri)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can try

```
library(stringr)
str_squish(str_replace(stri, "\\(.*\\)", ""))
# [1] "protein mono-ADP-ribosylation"           "negative regulation of viral life cycle"
# [3] "viral life cycle"
```

- `\\(.*\\)`: matches parenthesis and everything inside.
- `str_squish`: reduces repeated whitespace inside a string.